# SELECT Assíncrono com PYTHON

Tags: mysql, python, async, assincronismo

Olá a todos desde já agradeço!!

estou tentando fazer algumas conexões a um banco de dados MySQL de modo assíncrono onde haja disputa e print na tela o resultado que chegar primeiro... porém não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar...

```
import asyncio
import aiomysql

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def test_example():
    pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(host='',
                                port=3306,
                                user='administrator', 
                                password='',
                                db='sakila', 
                                loop=loop)

    pool2 = await aiomysql.create_pool(host='',
                                port=3306,
                                user='administrator', 
                                password='',
                                db='sakila', 
                                loop=loop)

    async with pool2.acquire() as conn2:
        async with conn2.cursor() as cur2:
            await cur2.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM filme")
            print(await cur2.fetchall())

    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM aluguel")
            print(await cur.fetchall())

    pool.close()
    pool2.close()
    await pool.wait_closed()

loop.run_until_complete(test_example())
```

este foi o ultimo código que cheguei, tentando realizar duas conexões ao banco e 2 consultas porém o código que está em cima sempre chega primeiro.. alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer eles serem concorrentes ?

Comment: Olá, Não sei se vc já conseguiu resolver esse problema, mas se vc remover o await na hora de definir as variáveis pool e pool2, acredito que resolveria.

Comment: Consegui resolver  no fórum internacional:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657392/select-async-with-python